# Wired connection sharing in Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: connection

Ubuntu has the option to share wired connections through a hotspot that I used for last 2 years. Now I switched on Kubuntu 17.04. I want the sharing option here also but I can't get it.

Can some tell me **How to share my current wired connection on Kubuntu 17.04 using Hotspot**

Comment: I use xubuntu variant and haven't tested kubuntu 17.04, but [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964918/sharing-connection-in-ubuntu-17-10) makes me wonder if running "kde5-nm-connection-editor" might open the tool you need.